# Migrating Chrome Extension Data from Chrome Local Storage to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, google-chrome-extension, plugins

**I'm new to this field. I'm making a plugin that stores text data to chrome local storage using chrome.storage.local.set api. All I want is to Migrate that data from chrome local storage to MongoDB server. Is there any way to do it??..

Comment: Read the data from the storage, connect to the server using `fetch`, send the data. There are lots of examples for every part.

Comment: @wOxxOm How can I create a running server in a plugin. Is there a way to do it? I mean like plugin is to be deployed as Zip file it's not clear as to connect to a server.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a server side for that.
What you can do is create a route in your server side that will save the data to the mongodb database and call it using the `fetch` api in your client's javascript.
I would recommend NodeJS and Express for that server side as it is coded in JS that you probably already know and the api is fairly simple.